ethers.js v6.3.0 provider 'getTransaction' call hangs forever
The following JS code uses a basic BNB Smart Chain endpoint from QuickNode and ethers.js v6.3.0 to iterate through all available transactions of the latest 10 blocks however the getTransaction call hangs forever at some point while iterating transactions of the very first block.
async function iterateTransactions() {
  try {
    let latestBlockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
    for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
      let currentBlock = await provider.getBlock(latestBlockNumber - i);
      for (var j = 0; j < currentBlock.transactions.length; j++) {
        const txInfo = await provider.getTransaction(currentBlock.transactions[j]);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

Any suggestions on why this is happening and alternative solutions would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.
